# read lines and remove a part of the line in C#

Tags: c#

im trying to make a engine in C# to read an part of my text file
this is a part of the text file

```
ver:14
D:\\demopath
2013-07-26  10:18a                  53 config.ini
2013-09-16  10:28a             7289119 data.res
2010-03-25  01:49a               41472 Dsetup.dll
2013-09-15  11:41p             7094272 demo.exe
2013-06-14  10:41P             4454454 lib\filetest.txt
```

and i also want that the engine skips the first 2 lines and only get the line parts with the files and show it in CMD console but it fails every time  i only get the whole lines and not the file

```
int counter = 0;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line == "ver:11")
    {
        counter = counter + 2;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        counter++;
    }
}
file.Close();
```

thanks by Selman22

now

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Skip(2).ToList();
foreach(var line in lines)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Can you come up with actual and expected result, also what have you tried?

Comment: If you're generating that file with `dir`, try `dir /b` instead.

Comment: i forgoted to add the source part and i also need the date and time to check the file date and time because it is for an automatic patcher

Comment: @Deathslayer don't you think it is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) ?

Comment: @Deathslayer You do realize that your first `if` branch will never be invoked? You're checking for `ver:11` while the file itself contains `ver:14`...

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @IronGeek that is already fixed by Selman22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Skip(2).ToList();
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var fileName = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3]

    Console.WriteLine(fileName.Replace("\\","/"));
 }
```

No need for old style,`StreamReader`, `while loop` etc. In this code you are reading all line with single method,and Skip first two line with [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

Comment: thank you for the replacing part of

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {  

                if (line == "ver:11")
                {
                    counter = counter + 2;
                }
                else
                {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                counter++;
                }

Comment: now i only need is help with getting only the last part of the line for example  it reads 2013-07-26  10:18a                  53 config.ini and outputs only config.ini

Comment: uhm... im getting this error while compiling
Error 1 The name 'StringSplitOption' does not exist in the current context d:\documenten\visual studio 2010\Projects\Patcher2.0\Patcher2.0\patch_engine.cs 33 51 Patcher2.0

btw im using .Net framework 4.0

Comment: sorry it should be `StringSplitOptions`

Comment: alright and one last small question how to replace the \ by / in the program?

Comment: use `.Replace("\\","/");`

Answer (score 0):

just call twice the ReadLine function and start to read your data.

```
file.ReadLine();
file.ReadLine();

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{  
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter++;
}
```